# How to have separate border cellspacing for table head and table body

Tags: html, css

Here, there are no gaps between columns/cells in both table header and table body. I need space between column in table head but there should be no gaps between columns in table body.

How to include space between columns in `thead` alone. i.e border space?

Below is the code I have tried.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunachalam408/81phjw9x/1/)

```css
table.OrderDetail {
    font-family: Arial;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.OrderDetail tbody {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.OrderDetail thead {
    padding: 7px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    color:#989898;
    font-size:10px;
}
.OrderNumber {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    text-align: left;
}
.OrderNumber thead {
    font-size:10px;
}
.OrderNumber tbody {
    font-size:15px;
}
tr.separating_line td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray; /* set border style for separated rows */
}
.OrderDetail td {
    padding: 10px 0; /* 10px top & bottom padding, 0px left & right */
}
.OrderDetail th {
    padding: 5px 0; /* 10px top & bottom padding, 0px left & right */
}
```

```html
<table class="OrderNumber" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Order Number</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>234456667</td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br></br>
<table class="OrderDetail" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Line Item Number</th>
            <th>Item Description</th>
            <th>Ship To Location</th>
            <th>Carrier</th>
            <th>Tracking Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="separating_line">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>$itemDescription</td>
            <td>$shipToLocation</td>
            <td>$carrier</td>
            <td style="color:#33CCFF">$trackingNumber</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="separating_line">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>$itemDescription</td>
            <td>$shipToLocation</td>
            <td>$carrier</td>
            <td style="color:#33CCFF">$trackingNumber</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have used border-collapse: collapse at table. This makes all border continuos. I need it be continuos at body and not continuos at head level of table. is it even possible?

Comment: Can you show your html?

Comment: I think my question is little mis leading, I m sorry for that. I mean the column separation  I.e border. I need gaps in border of thead but there should be no space in tbody. I have used border collapse in table which makes the border continuous. I want it to be continuous  at tbody level but not at thead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will help you? Set the border width for the th cells. It makes a separation between the headings, I think that's what you ask for...?

```
.OrderDetail th {
    padding: 5px 0; /* 10px top & bottom padding, 0px left & right */
    border-right: 5px solid white;
}
.OrderDetail th:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/81phjw9x/4/)

Answer (score 1):

This could be what you're after. You need to target the cells directly.

```
.OrderDetail thead th { padding: 7px; }
.OrderDetail tbody td { padding: 3px; }
```

Comment: I think my question is little mis leading, I m sorry for that. I mean the column separation  I.e border. I need gaps in border of thead but there should be no space in tbody. I have used border collapse in table which makes the border continuous. I want it to be continuous  at tbody level but not at thead.